# Handling a duplicate scenario in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-web-api2

I have a API call which in turn calls a stored procedure internally to retrieve the result set which is finally rendered as a JSON response for the GET API call.

The signature of the stored procedure is:

```
api_get_candidatelist @candidatecode
```

Ideally, the `candidatecode` is unique. But if there is some faulty data manipulation in back-end there is a possibility of duplicate `candidatecode`.

All I want to do is check for duplicates at the beginning of the stored-procedure...and raise a error....so that finally the API call renders a `404` or `500`.

What is the optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using DISTINCT clause in your SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an indexed view to automaticaly compute num. of candidate codes

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CandidateCodeCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT CandidateCode, COUNT_BIG(CandidateCode) AS Cnt
FROM dbo.Candidates
GROUP BY CandidateCode;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_CandidateCodeCount_CandidateCode
ON dbo.CandidateCodeCount(CandidateCode);
GO
```

and then you could use `IF EXISTS` to check duplicates:

```
IF EXITS(SELECT * FROM dbo.CandidateCodeCount WITH(NOEXPAND) WHERE CandidateCode = @CandidateCode AND Cnt > 1)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Duplicate code.', 16, 1);
    -- RETURN; ?
END
```

Question for OP: what should happen if a concurrent connection tries to `INSERT` a duplicate code during `api_get_candidatelist` execution ?

**Note:** on long term I would try to eliminate duplicates and then I would create an unique index on `CandidateCode` column.